# multiple urls using a for loop in scrapy

Tags: python, loops, url, scrapy

i want to scrape information from multiple urls. I use the following code but it doesn't work. May someone please points me to where I have gone wrong?

```py
import scrapy


class spider1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spider1"
    domain = "http://www.amazon.com/dp/"
    ASIN = ['B01LA6171I', 'B00OUKHTLO', 'B00B7LUVZK']

    def start_request(self):
        for i in ASIN:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=domain+i, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.css("span#productTitle::text").extract_first().strip()
        ASIN_ext = response.xpath("//input[@name='ASIN']/@value").extract_first()
        data = {"ASIN": ASIN_ext, "title": title, }
        yield data
```

Comment: What happens if you print out the results?  Is it getting the data at all?  Also have you tried making an item for your output?  https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

Comment: 2019-06-22 21:06:18 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-06-22 21:06:18 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here goes my solution for loop a url over a page/1 to page/50

```
urls = ['http://www.example.com/page/' + str(i) for i in range(1, 51)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in method's name: it should be `start_requests` instead of `start_request`.